# Agrupar por fecha filtrada SQL

Tags: sql-server

Estoy usando SQL server para lanzar esta consulta.

Lo que necesito es agrupar por la fecha filtrada ('20210211 06:00:01' and '20210212 06:00:01') y guárdame la última fecha (20210212)

```
SELECT (CONVERT(varchar,FECHAHORA,3)) AS FECHAHORA, 
SUM(RED1) AS RED1
FROM [DB_3CS].[dbo].[REGISTROS]
WHERE FECHAHORA between '20210211 06:00:01' and '20210212 06:00:01' 
GROUP BY  CONVERT(varchar, FECHAHORA, 3)
```

Resultado:

```
FECHAHORA   RED1
11/02/21    395540,909926891
12/02/21    105172,74647522
```

Resultado deseado:

```
FECHAHORA   RED1
12/02/2021  500713,6564
```

Gracias!

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(varchar,FECHAHORA,3)) AS FECHAHORA, 
SUM(RED1) AS RED1
FROM [DB_3CS].[dbo].[REGISTROS]
WHERE FECHAHORA between '20210211 06:00:01' and '20210212 06:00:01' 
GROUP BY  MAX(CONVERT(varchar, FECHAHORA, 3))
```

Comment: Perdón, sobra todo el group by

Comment: Si sobra todo el `GROUP BY` no lo pongas en comentarios, dale a [edit] y déjalo correcto. Además, ten en cuenta que las respuestas de solo código no son bien recibidas pues realmente no *enseñan* nada y alguien con pocos conocimientos podría no enterarse de qué está haciendo tu código. Te recomiendo leer [answer] y hacer el [tour] para entender cómo funciona StackOverflow.